# search plus symbol using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to search the **+** symbol in the table using jquery and then add css style in that td.
Can anyone help?

Here is my code :

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="flex1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="hDiv">
            <th>
                <div rel="job_id" class="text-left field-sorting ">Job id</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div rel="tour" class="text-left field-sorting ">Tour</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="text-left">1</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="text-left">6 Day Hongkong</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="erow">
            <td>
                <div class="text-left">2</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="text-left">6 Day Macau +</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="erow">
            <td>
                <div class="text-left">2</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="text-left">6 Day + UK</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/b6Ym8/)</kbd>

```
$('#flex1 td:contains("+")').css();
```

or

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/b6Ym8/1)</kbd>

```
$('#flex1 td:contains("+")').addClass('ClassName');
```

---

[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Comment: hi tushar, do I need to use the .each function ?

Comment: @redcoder No just wrap this code in [DOM Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: Strangely enough it doesn't works on my development site at http://acornasia.com.my/job/index.php/main/jobs_management . I use addClass('extra_address') but it is not added to the text with + sign.See the FROM column

Comment: this is my js script : <script type="text/javascrpt">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#flex1 td:contains("+")').addClass('extra_address');
    
    });
</script>

Comment: I think it load from ajax cause I put a simple console.log("Test") in that script, and nothing appear on the Firebug

Comment: @redcoder Use this code in ajax `success:function(){ //code here }`

Comment: Well tushar,your code is actually work.I just realise the script color is all black in my editor.it shud be color coded if the code is a js script. So I deleted all the script and re-type your code carefully.And it works now.. Thank you so much for your time and effort

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a wonderful selector called [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), so this is actually as simple as:

```
$('td:contains("+")').addClass('blue')
```

[Click here to see this in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/3NCJ7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td:contains("+")').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('addMyCss');    
}
```

And after that you can customize addMyCss class with your css. I hope that will help you.